# Background audio: why does completing the background audio task deferral not terminate the process?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1

My background audio task will call [`BackgroundTaskDeferral.Complete`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.applicationmodel.background.backgroundtaskdeferral.complete.aspx) when the task instance receives the [`Canceled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.applicationmodel.background.ibackgroundtaskinstance.canceled.aspx) or [`Completed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.applicationmodel.background.backgroundtaskregistration.completed.aspx) events, as per the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn642090.aspx). This can happen for a number of reasons, such as another app starts playing music, or because of an incoming call.

But what does [`BackgroundTaskDeferral.Complete`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.applicationmodel.background.backgroundtaskdeferral.complete.aspx) do exactly? It doesn't terminate the background process, because if I switch back to my app and play a song, the background process will not re-initialize and happily play the song *as if it were never cancelled in the first place*.

Perhaps it just means that the OS can now terminate the background process *at some later time*, which is fine, but if I switch back to my foreground app and start playing music, I don't want the OS to terminate my background process -- I want to "un-complete" the deferral in this case. How can I do this?

Or am I going about this the wrong way? Should I code my foreground app to expect that the background process could terminate at any time, and I shouldn't rely on specific times (like app startup) to instantiate the background process and assume that it will always be running as long as my foreground app is visible?

If the latter is what I should be doing, then it seems odd because you're supposed to wait for the background process to initialize before playing any music, but then how do I check upfront if the background process has not started so that I can do the wait?